# Need help installing node-dev

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js and I am trying to install node-dev. Everytime I try to install I get his following error message:

```
npm WARN deprecated object-keys@0.2.0: Please update to the latest object-keys
/usr/local/bin/node-dev -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-dev/bin/node-dev
node-dev@2.6.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-dev
├── filewatcher@1.1.2
├── resolve@1.1.6
├── node-notifier@4.1.2 (which@1.0.9, shellwords@0.1.0, clone@0.1.19, growly@1.2.0, semver@4.3.3)
├── dynamic-dedupe@0.2.0 (xtend@2.0.6)
└── dateformat@1.0.11 (get-stdin@4.0.1, meow@3.1.0)
```

I know it didn't install because when I run a script, it brings me back to the command prompt, instead of waiting for  a change in file for it to restart automatically.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: npm install -g node-dev

Comment: @MartinGolpashin ?? Still produces the same results

Comment: That’s not an error; it’s a warning. What’s your script, and what does it look like when you try to run it?